# Conflicts when making a ValidatorRequest in Axum Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a Request Validator in Rust, but I keep running into some conflicts in the Axum library

```
use async_trait::async_trait;
use axum::extract::{rejection::JsonRejection, FromRequest};
use axum::{body::HttpBody, http::Request, BoxError, Json};
use axum::response::{IntoResponse, Response};
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use thiserror::Error;
use validator::Validate;
use crate::v3::config::response::ApiErrorResponse;

#[derive(Debug, Error)]
pub enum RequestError {
    #[error(transparent)]
    ValidationError(#[from] validator::ValidationErrors),
    #[error(transparent)]
    JsonRejection(#[from] JsonRejection),
}
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Default)]
pub struct ValidatedRequest<T>(pub T);

#[async_trait]
impl<T, S, B> FromRequest<S, B> for ValidatedRequest<T>
    where
        T: DeserializeOwned + Validate,
        S: Send + Sync,
        B: HttpBody + Send + 'static,
        B::Data: Send,
        B::Error: Into<BoxError>,
{
    type Rejection = RequestError;

    async fn from_request(req: Request<B>, state: &S) -> Result<Self, Self::Rejection> {
        let Json(value) = Json::<T>::from_request(req, state).await?;
        value.validate()?;
        Ok(ValidatedRequest(value))
    }
}

impl IntoResponse for RequestError {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response {
        match self {
            RequestError::ValidationError(_) => {
                ApiErrorResponse::send(400, Some(self.to_string().replace('\n', ", ")))
            }
            RequestError::JsonRejection(_) => ApiErrorResponse::send(400, Some(self.to_string())),
        }
    }
}
```

```
impl<T, S, B> FromRequest<S, B> for ValidatedRequest<T> -> Here is the error
```

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `FromRequest<_, axum_core::extract::private::ViaParts>` for type `ValidatedRequest<_>`
  --> src/v3/error/request.rs:21:1
   |
21 | / impl<T, S, B> FromRequest<S, B> for ValidatedRequest<T>
22 | |     where
23 | |         T: DeserializeOwned + Validate,
24 | |         S: Send + Sync,
25 | |         B: HttpBody + Send + 'static,
26 | |         B::Data: Send,
27 | |         B::Error: Into<BoxError>,
   | |_________________________________^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `axum_core`:
           - impl<S, T> FromRequest<S, axum_core::extract::private::ViaParts> for T
             where S: Send, S: Sync, T: FromRequestParts<S>;
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `axum::extract::FromRequestParts<_>` for type `v3::error::request::ValidatedRequest<_>`
   = note: upstream crates may add a new impl of trait `axum::body::HttpBody` for type `axum_core::extract::private::ViaParts` in future versions
```

I can't find any resources about this problem on the net. How could I solve the problem? Is there a way?

I should be able to validate a request with a body from the user

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while upgrading a project that used custom `FromRequest` extractors to latest axum.

It took me a while to notice it too, but the root issue is that the signature of `FromRequest` has changed - instead of implementing `FromRequest<S, B>` you're now supposed to implement just `FromRequest<S>`, without 2nd type parameter. Here are the latest docs showcasing an example: https://docs.rs/axum/0.7.4/axum/extract/index.html#implementing-fromrequest

Once you change the signature, the problem should go away.

Here is an official example showing how to do validation with the updated `FromRequest` signature: https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/9e319490798f6a35b24f128fc8c00f4f312d0bdd/examples/validator/src/main.rs#L59-L73

Comment: Ok. and how can I validate if I remove B? Because I want to use validate in my DTO

Comment: You still get the body, it's just now always an exact type (`Bytes`) instead of a generic `B` type parameter. There is also an official example showing how to do validation with FromRequest that might be helpful: https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/9e319490798f6a35b24f128fc8c00f4f312d0bdd/examples/validator/src/main.rs#L59-L73